# Magento Product Attribute "Manage Label / Options" content not showing

Tags: product, upgrade

I have been given a task of upgrading an old store's **Magento ver. 1.7.0.2** to **Magento ver. 1.9.2.0.**

Had quite a few issues which seems to be normal when it comes to Magento upgrades, but got all sorted after some nights work. However there seems to be a minor issue on the backend where if you navigate to the following...

```
> Admin > Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > [Any Custom Attribute] > Edit Product Attribute
```

The "Manage Label / Options" tab displays nothing if you click it. You can see what I mean in the screenshot provided.

[image]

I still have the old system backed up (Magento ver. 1.7.0.2) and it displays the following on the same page

[image]

I have tried searching for someone with a similar issue, without any results. Have also tried looking into the phtml files, but could not find any errors there. Nor are there any errors with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on. Tried deleting cache and reindexing without luck.

Hope someone can help me with this issue, and thanks in advance! If there is any additional information required, I'll be happy to provide it.

Although I believe it is an irrelevant issue, my var/log gives me the following

```
2015-09-03T03:30:37+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: productId  in **/app/design/frontend/default/helloresponsive/template/catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml on line 32
```

Comment: Did you check the logs in `var/log`? More information on debugging can be found at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: Yeah, checked that. Only thing that gives me is a different issue on the frontend 

`2015-09-03T03:30:36+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: productId  in ***/helloresponsive/template/catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml on line 32`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem! I was missing the following folder, which I got from the old system:

```
adminhtml/default/default/template/jr/*
```